To what extent can citizens of democracies be held responsible for the acts of their governments?
The United States has often the case used the justification of removing a dictator as a reason to go to war. This has inflicted untold suffering onto the peoples of many nations. This brings into question as to whether or not the citizens in a democracy are responsible for the actions of their democratic government, and if those of a dictatorship are not.

This is more of a philosophical than a practical/political Q. And the answers will probably vary somewhat with the philosopher.

Ibid.

TBH, I took a look at https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/collective-responsibility/ but it seems not a topic I'm confy summarizing. Much that's been written about it is... seems so convoluted.

Political questions often contain quite a number of philosophical/ethical considerations. Otherwise all questions about fairness would be moot. However, this question could maybe come up with better (or more balanced) examples and definitely use more research.

Weirdly the Politics SE site rules don't make any mention of political philosophy. It says "For purposes of this site, we define politics as: The end result of conflicting egos working themselves out through matters of policy." But this would definitely be on-topic in a university politics department. So I don't know, maybe this is off-topic, but it should be on-topic if this site is to be more than childish arguments or people too lazy to read newspapers asking for summaries of the latest news (the dominant categories of other questions).

What do you mean by "responsible" or "held responsible"? What would it mean to hold citizens responsible for the acts of their government? It seems a vague question.

@Lag Good point. This question should clarify that. Probably it means by some higher moral authority, possibly some international law. Like for example even if Putin dies, could Ukrainians sue every single Russian who voted for him for damages. Just an example.

@Lag - 'held responsible' implies, to me, policies like blockades or economic sanctions, when they are broadly targeted. Cuba might be a nearly ideal example. Madeline Albright's infamous comment saying the death of half a million Iraqi children as a result of sanctions (in the name of human rights) was "worth it", is another finely distilled motivation for this question. https://www.aljazeera.com/opinions/2022/3/25/lets-remember-madeleine-albright-as-who-she-really-was

It is generally accepted in political theory that voting is an act of violence against strangers, as such citizens use force when they vote, and should be held responsible. You can't have it both ways: if some vote for a representative legitimizes all later decisions by them, you can't also say that voters are not responsible.

I can understand the temptation to say "well, you voted for these people, so you're responsible for anything and everything they do", but like most things in politics, it's just not that simple. In any representative democracy, and particularly the United States, there are various mitigating factors at play:

Things like voter eligibility restrictions and voter turnout mean that, while a politician may be elected by a majority of voters, they are rarely elected by a majority of citizens. For example, in the 2020 US election, Joe Biden received 51.3% of the popular vote, but only 24.5% of US citizens actually voted for him (81.28 million votes / 331.4 million US population).
Voters may engage in strategic voting, voting for a candidate not because they agree with their policies, but because they have the best chance of beating another candidate whose policies they strongly disagree with. (This is the entire crux of the American two-party system - many people vote for Trump or Biden not because they actually like one of them, but simply because they dislike the other one more.)
Politicians frequently implement policies that weren't in their manifestos, or that directly contradict them, due to either unforeseen circumstances, realising that what they promised isn't feasible, realising (ironically) a certain promise isn't popular, or of course, straight-up dishonesty. Can the people who voted George W. Bush into power be held responsible for the Iraq War when they couldn't possibly have known that such a war would happen when they voted for him? Or to use a more benign example, can the people who voted Bush Sr into power be held responsible for him raising taxes, when he explicitly promised them he wouldn't do that?
If a government, even an elected one, does something its citizens don't like - such as invading another country - there's not an awful lot those citizens can actually do about it in the short term. Hold protests? The government doesn't have to listen to them. Vote them out? The next election might still be a while off. Overthrow them? Sometimes that works, and sometimes it doesn't.
There is, of course, the possibility of a democratically-elected leader proceeding to subvert democracy and turn a country into a dictatorship, at which point the lines become blurred. If I vote someone into power, and they then abolish elections and become dictator for life, can I be blamed for anything they do from that point forward? It circles back round to my earlier points: I can't have known that they'd do that, and now that they have, there's not much I can do to stop them.


Nice answer, although it kind of raises more questions than the question itself. Maybe it should be added that in the other way around when you don't vote but tolerate bad stuff you can still bear responsibility, otherwise Germans after WW2 could have simply said, sorry, didn't vote for the war or the Holocaust, not my responsibility. On a more individual level, in many countries it's for example a crime to not help others in emergencies if one can. Simply doing nothing doesn't mean to be free of responsibility.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Germans were not punished because of a generic objective and universal law that "when you don't vote but tolerate bad stuff you can still bear responsibility", but because they were defeated in a war and occupied, so the occupying powers had the power to decide whatever they wanted, for whatever justifications. The Soviets killed even more people in forced labor camps than the Germans did, but they were never conquered and occupied, so there was never any "bearing of responsibility". Arguably China does it right now but there is no reaction of any significant level.

TBH I'm not inclined to dive into the philosophical arguments on this because they seem so fruitless. Regardless of what one thinks of how exactly collective responsibility is to be distributed in a population (and there are a lot of theories about this), few practical means have been devised. War reparations, whether explicitly called that or just 'post-war aid' are implicitly paid by the taxpayers in the country sending them, if they're a state effort, which in many cases they are. A more practical question would be how are these determined.

There certainly are proponents of the philosophy you suggest, e.g.  Michael Walzer:

The greater the possibility of free action in the communal sphere, the greater the degree of guilt for evil deeds done in the name of everyone.

Agreeing to that can, in an extreme interpretation, have some unexpected consequences though. E.g. that would imply that almost no sanctions can be imposed on dictatorships because those are mostly passed on the population. And if the dictator is dead and didn't have a (personal) piggy bank in Switzerland (in a generic sense), everyone is sorry out of luck in recovering any war damages a dictator caused. So, it's not exactly uncontroversial to adopt that, even if it may sound reasonable on a first reading.
This discussion is less than purely academic. Some countries have [later] rejected paying debts accumulated while they were governed by dictators--the so-called "odious debt". But then, the only reasonable way to prevent that situation is to not lend to dictators to begin with

If odiousness were declared in advance, banks would avoid lending to odious regimes and would have no fear that a successful popular debt-relief campaign would arise to nullify their outstanding loans.

But how's that different from sanctioning a country run by a dictator?

N.B. for some (critical) commentary on US forgiving the Iraqi/Saddam debt (but not others') see https://thewalrus.ca/the-dictator-debt-catch/

Upvoted for the war reparations. Regarding "it's not our fault what our dictator did" I'd like to refer you to an answer regarding what can prevent dictatorships ... As an example, even though elections played a role in Hitler's assumption of power, he was probably eventually the quintessential dictator. Nonetheless, the world, including many Germans, held the German Nazi populace responsible.

History is written by the victors. While vanquished on many occasions were made responsible for the crimes committed by non-democratic regimes, democracies, dictatorships and totalitarian regimes alike often manage to shrug the responsibility for their crimes.
Germany
German collective guilt for WW2 and Holocaust is the most manifest example. It is perhaps less well-known that the same applies to Austrians and Italians, who are taught that they bear responsibility for the past crimes of their countries, even if they had little say or even were not born at the time. In Germany and Austria this responsibility is enshrined in law and the official government policies.
Turkey
On the other hand, the Armenian genocide has little recognition in Turkey, and was only recently officially acknowledged by the US Congress, although some Turks privately feel guilty about it.
Communist regimes
Likewise, the crimes committed by the Communist states remain largely attributed to regimes or particular persons in power, but not viewed as a national responsibility.
France
There is some effort in western democracies to recognize the crimes associated with Nazi collaboration and their colonial past. E.g., Vel d'Hiv roundup or the atrocities committed in Algeria and Indochina by France.
Britain and the US
I am less aware of national guilt in English-speaking countries. The colonial past of the British Empire and the genocide of the native Americans are well documented, and affect government policies, but there is little official statements in terms of accepting self-guilt. Likewise, being the winners inn WW2 seems to have absolved the British and Americans from atoning for the bombings of Hiroshima&Nagasaki and Dresden or the inaction in response to extermination of Jews (which was known to allies as early as 1942 - not 1945, after the US army liberated death camps, as commonly believed; see also Witold's report).
There is also little recognition of the crimes committed by the US in Vietnam, even for well-publicized events like My Lai massacre, which involved cover-up but such later well-known politicians as Colin Powell (at the time he was an officer charged with investigating the incident.)
Wars in Iraq, Afghanistan, and Libya are largely seen as justified - never mind more than a million victims. During the period of 2000-2008 one could indeed meet abroad many Americans trying in private conversations to dissociate them from George W. Bush policies.

With Communism it gets more complicated, as there are routine attempts to peg Communist mishaps on ethnic Russians specifically, including this site's question and answer sections. There's also a different between implicating responsibility and actually holding responsible.

@alamar Yes, I forgot to mention this - indeed, eastern Europeans often attribute their misery to the Russian domination, rather than to the ideology.

That leads to an observation that there is a tendency to implicate a subset of citizens responsible for acts of an illiberal regime, rather than all citizens. Such subset is usually a majority (therefore, not directly power wielding) but may exclude significant chunks of population.

@alamar the question aims at democracies, where supposedly all citizens (or at least the majority) share the responsibility. So I prefer not to focus on the Communists (although they have many sympathizers in the west.)

With regards to Turkey, the genocide has actually happened under a different (illiberal) goverment (Ottomans), in a country with a significantly different ethnic and religious composition than present day Turkey. So the Republic of Türkiye could have shrugged it off more efficiently.

@alamar it was quite Turkish affair. The same argument could apply to nearly any case - e.g., Germany has a different government now and not quite the same territory.

It kind of was, but it's almost impossible to peg it on ethnic Turks. For starters, directly attacking an ethnicity or religion is not tolerated in modern discourse so it would be easy to counter such claims and often put the claimaint in a bad light themself.

If a person wasn't even born when a horrible event occurred, it seems unreasonable to suggest they are in any way responsible for it.

@Lag we are talking not about legal responsibility, but about guilt/shame. So why not? - People do take pride in the military glory, scientific achievements, economic prosperity, football victories, etc. of their country - most of them achieved without their participation and often before their birth. Why shouldn't they similarly share the guilt/shame?

@RogerV. 1. I didn't use the word legal, you and OP used "responsibility" on its own and so did I. 2. I don't think people "should" share credit in things that occurred in which they had no influence, either. We might feel happy or sad about it but if you weren't born then you could not have affected it, which means you are not responsible for it.

@Lag You can say that both of these are part of your "legacy", though.

@Lag think of it as a part of one's cultural identity. This is something that people absorb as children - from their family, school, media, etc. And also something that, as experience shows, they cannot easily abandon, even after living for many years in a different country.

@RogerV. Indeed, feelings of pride/guilt/shame about things they have no involvement in is "something that people absorb as children - from their family, school, media" - not something they "should" feel.

@Lag I think creating a person without any cultural roots is both impossible and undesirable. Humans are parts of a society, not simply individuals in vacuum.

@RogerV. I didn't suggest we can or should "create a person without any cultural roots" or that "humans are ... simply individuals in a vacuum." I think feelings of pride/guilt/shame about long ago events are not prerequisites for cultural roots. I've experienced a lot of culture without people volunteering their cultural pride/guilt/shame about long ago events. There seems to be a culture among some people of wanting others to feel guilt/shame about long ago events.

@Lag In your opinion, do the War of Independence and the American civil war constitute a part of the American culture? What about more recent events, like wars in Iraq and Afghanistan?

@RogerV. In your opinion, "should" today's German children be made to feel guilty about Germany's behaviour from 1933 to 1945? I don't think they should. Do you think guilt is a necessary condition for Germany to have distinct, fascinating and wonderful culture? I don't think it is. There are many parts of German culture that don't seem to depend on it. There are more feelings than guilt and shame. We should teach history and that some things were/are moral wrongs (or rights), but to me it's weird if we make children feel guilty about events that occurred several decades ago.

@Lag What happened from 1933 to 1945 is a part of German culture, and a German should accept it alongside all the beautiful/fascinating/wonderful parts of it. Somebody who waxes about German philosophers and poets, but fails to acknowledge that these very people and their work contributed to the genocide, is paving a way to a new one.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Speaking as a German born long after the war, generally there is no "collective guilt" seen in the current generation, but we (including current politicians) sure take "collective responsibility" – mostly in the form of making sure it doesn't happen again. (Of course, not everyone (there are a growing number of right-populists), and even the people who adhere to it not all agree how exactly this should look like – e.g. some derive an unconditional support for Israel from it, while others now say that other Genocides also need to be stopped, including ones done by Israel.)

Democratic processes in a country like USA work with significant delay. Federal elections are held every two years, presidential elections every four years. It may take more time before independent press digs out enough information and analysis for the society to become aware the state is doing something clearly wrong.
Hence the nation likely should only be held responsible for activities that continue over multiple elections for decades, because in such cases activities are likely popular between the voters. Many military actions as taken by USA were way too short for democratic processes to have effect on them.

This is the logic of terrorists and war criminals.
One of the most depressing parts of the history of WWII was how the Soviets treated German civilians once the tide had turned and the counter-invasion of Germany had begun. I won't go into the details here, but the record is clear that Stalin received reports of these atrocities with complete indifference.
And how do modern-day terrorists justify their indiscriminate slaughter of non-combatants? By pointing to the actions of their government, over which the victims have no meaningful level of control.
As others have pointed out, the common citizen rarely has any meaningful degree of power over the government, even in a functioning republic.
Making the accountability into a formal process, with all of the niceties of trials, only adds a layer of hypocrisy onto the malice behind this thinking. Yes, the victorious allies put the architects of the Nazi war machine on trial, but this was limited to officials who held real power.
Blaming one person for the actions of another is fundamentally unjust.
